# How to copy and link collection to other scene?

Tags: scene

How to copy collection to other scene ? And how if i want this collection to be linked, so if i change the collection setting in one scene , it will update automatically in other scene.

Comment: I would like to know this too, please.

Answer (score 11):

1. **Ensure that the scene to which you want your collection to be linked is selected.**
2. **In an "Outliner" editor window, ensure that the "Display Mode" in the toolbar is set to "Blender File" or "Scenes".**

[image]

3. **Find the collection you want to link under "Collections" or "Scene Collection", and activate "Link to Scene" under its alternate-click context menu.**

[image]

Comment: You don't have to set the Outliner Display Mode to "Blender File". For working between scenes the Display Mode "Scenes" is quite handy.
Example: Scene1 with Collection1, Scene2 with Collection2 and Scene3 is empty. Select Scene3 in the Outliner. Right-click on Collection1 > Link to Scene, right-click Collection2 > Link to Scene.
Now Scene3 holds linked versions of Collection1 and Collection2. It's the same like the answer, but I think "Scenes" has a better hierarchy for working between scenes than "Blender File".

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I don't believe that would work if the collection in question isn't already linked to *any* scene? I'm pretty sure I've had that happen before, and that it was the original reason I found this question— Maybe from appending, maybe from unlinking, or maybe from deleting the scene which originally held the collection.

Comment: You might be correct, but as I understand the question, he wants a linked copy of a collection from one scene to another, and changing things in one collection changes the linked collection. So as a premise there is at least one collection linked to one scene, which is the one he wants to copy. And afterwards there are two scenes, each holding a copy of said collection... so unlinked collections should be no problem.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That is true. As "Blender File" also works in more cases, but "Scenes" has a better workflow for the question, I've edited the answer to include both.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm still learning using the compositor, in the beginning I found it not very helpful but now I see things that are better to do there.  I only wish andio would mark questions as "Answered" ;-)